# Create a new object for the newly registered user

Tags: django, django-1.7

I am very new to django, so please bear with me. What I want is whenever a new user is registered I would like to create an `About` for that user. How will I do that? Please help me. Thank you.

views:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return render(request, 'register.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
        return render(request, 'register.html', {'form':form})
```

model:

```
class About(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    place = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't looked at forms yet, you should read these links:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/

If you need to see some code to get started,

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.Form) or (models.Form) '''You should read up on these two'''
    #define form attributes here

def clean(self):
    '''write your validations here'''
    return self.cleaned_data
def save(self)

    data = self.cleaned_data
    about = About()
    about.user = data.get("user")
    about.gender = data.get("gender")
    about.place = data.get("place")
    year = data.get("year")
    month = data.get("month")
    day = data.get("day")
    about.dob = datetime(year, month, day).date()
    about.save()
```

Also Profile or Member would be a more intuitive name of your model than About. Just giving my two cents. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you will be creating an `About` instance for every user, regardless of how they're created (e.g. user input, through the admin, or through the shell) [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/signals/#module-django.dispatch) can be very helpful.

So in your case:

```
class About(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    place = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)

def user_post_save(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    """create an about when a new user is created

    data:
       sender - The model class. (User)
       instance - The actual instance being saved.
       created - Boolean; True if a new record was created.

       *args, **kwargs - Capture the unneeded `raw` and `using`(1.3) arguments.
    """
    if created:
        About.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(user_post_save, sender=User)
```

Now whenever a new `User` is created, and `About` will automatically be created for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `save` method on the `UserCreationForm` by extending the class to make every time you call save, the `About` object will be automatically created.

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        about = About()
        about.user = instance
        about.gender = 1
        about.place = "Indonesia"
        about.save()
        return instance
```

Or, you can use `AutoOneToOne` field with [django-annoying](https://github.com/skorokithakis/django-annoying)